# How to install docker on Ubuntu 20.10!

Tags: docker

Does someone knows how to install Docker with PPA packages to Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: I faced the same issue and this helped me: 
`sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal containerd.io`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hi mire12 and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I hope you find the site useful and continue to use Ubuntu for years to come!

If you take a look at [Docker's Installation Page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) you'll see that in order to configure the repository you are going to install `docker` from you'll run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

If you look closely you'll see the command `lsb_release -cs` is run. If you try and execute that on your machine you'll get the distribution's codename. For Ubuntu 20.10 that would be `groovy` as the release's name is *Groovy Gorilla* (really cool release name if you ask me :P). I'm not 100% sure this is what you'll get as I haven't updated yet though... Either way, I'm certain the output of `lsb_release -cs` is none of `focal` (20.04), `bionic` (18.04), or `xenial` (16.04) which are the ones `docker` currently supports.

Then, if you run the `sudo add-apt-command` you'll be adding the following repo: `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy stable`

This doesn't exist as `docker` only supports the three releases I listed before.

You then have two options.

1. The first one is to wait until they release a `docker` version for 20.10. I'm not sure if they will do so and if they do I don't know how long it'll take.
2. You can manually run the command swapping `lsb_release -cs` for `focal` to use the `docker` version for *Focal Fossa*. This doesn't guarantee compatibility but I have done it some other times and it worked out fine. If you try to walk down this road you'll then have to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   focal \
   stable"
```

I hope this works out for you! If it doesn't you could also try to manually download the `.deb` file for `docker` and install that with `dpkg`. You can read more on that on the page I linked at the beginning (i.e. [this one](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) :P)

P.D:

The `$()` structure used in the `add-apt-repository` command is called a *Command Substitution* in Bash's lingo. What it's basically doing is replacing the whole `$()` structure with the output of whatever is within the brackets. In our case that amounts to replacing `$(lsb_release -cs)` with `groovy`. That's why manually fixing a release codename is a feasible workaround.

You can read more on *Command Substitution* on Bash's *manpage* which you can read by running `man bash` if Bash is installed. It's the default shell on Ubuntu so chances are it's the one you commonly use. The *manpage* is worth a read; I learned a lot by doing so :P. I'm citing a bit on *Command Substitution* explaining the above from the *manpage* so that you don't have to comb through it:

```
Command Substitution
       Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace 
       the command name.  There are two forms:

              $(command)
       or
              `command`

       Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing
       the command substitution with the standard output of the command, 
       with any trailing newlines  deleted.
       Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during
       word splitting.  The command substitution $(cat file) can be 
       replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).
```

You can also read it online [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) but I find reading *manpages* on a terminal emulator to be more appealing. I love the *old-schooly* vibe it has :P

Comment: The answer was useful even for a seasoned Linux user like myself ))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind words ADNow :)

Comment: `docker-ce` is available now for  `groovy`.

Comment: @GAD3R in the 'test' channel - not 'stable'  -  for me

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Right! thank you.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder A stable release is now available.

Comment: Dont forget at the beginning `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`